# Script of welcome / goodbye to discord js bot Error

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

He is giving me this script of welcome/goodbye to Discord error and he has already tried many things if someone helps me I would appreciate it very much, Thanks

```js
module.exports = (client) => {
    const channelIdA = '718596514305277972'
    
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
       console.log("Someone joined the server")
       
         const messageA = `message`

          const channel = (channelIdA)
          channel.send(messageA)
       })
   }
   
   module.exports = (client) => {
    const channelIdB = '890891192995303424'
    
    client.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => {
       console.log("Someone left the server")
       
         const messageB = `message`
          
          const channel = (channelIdB)
          channel.send(messageB)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to send a message to a channel by calling the `.send()` method. However, you are calling the method on a string. The `send()` method only exists on [text based channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/TextBasedChannels). To send a message to a specific channel, replace your message sending code with this

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", members => {
 client.channels.cache.get("REPLACE WITH CHANNEL ID").send("message")
});

client.on("guildMemberRemove", members => {
 client.channels.cache.get("REPLACE WITH OTHER CHANNEL ID").send(" other message")
});
```

If the above does not work, try this:
(works without cache)

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
 const channel = await client.channels.fetch("REPLACE WITH CHANNEL ID")
 channel.send(`${member.user.username}, welcome`)
});

client.on("guildMemberRemove", async (member) => {
 const channel = await client.channels.fetch("REPLACE WITH OTHER CHANNEL ID")
 channel.send(`${member.user.username} has left`)
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much but if I want to use <@ $ {member.id}> or $ {member.guild.memberCount}, how do I do it?
When I leave the server it says goodbye
When I enter the server it says goodbye and welcome
And it worked the frist

Comment: `channels.fetch()` returns a Promise, so it doesn't have a `.send()` method and you'll need to resolve it first.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros whoops I'll update my answer now

Comment: @Bertogim it looks like a new question.

Comment: Ok thanks it works fine 100%
Maybe in some future I ask a question of role reaction or something else, thank you very much

Comment: Mark this answer as correct if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting the channel using [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch). If you already have the channel in cache (something happened in the channel after the bot started), you can use the channels cache as well.